# Views: How do you view the query?

Tags: 7, views

How do you view the query that a 'View' is using to gather data from the database?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to `admin/structure/views/settings`, check `Show information and statistics about the view during live preview` and then `Show the SQL query` checkbox that will appear below.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see a preview of the query being used when viewing the view as opposed to editing it you can use [`hook_views_pre_execute()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_execute/7):

```
function MYMODULE_views_pre_execute(&$view) {
  dpq($view->build_info['query']);
}
```

The [`dpq()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpq/7) function is provided by the [devel module](https://drupal.org/project/devel) so you will need to have that installed for this to work.