# How to make exposed timestamp filter accept human readable date

Tags: views, 8

I'm using Drupal 8. I created a new content type (title, body, image, date).
The date is a **timestamp** field.

I used the [devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and the [Realistic Dummy Content module](https://www.drupal.org/project/realistic_dummy_content) to generate a test content for my view **test**.

I created my **test** view and chose the date as an exposed filter.

Here is my configuration:
[image]

And this is my view:
[image]

When I apply my filter, I want to say all contents having a date **greater than** my input:

If I test with **01/31/2018 - 02:54**, nothing was changed!

But If I test with the unix value: **1538323253**, my filter works well!

Any idea please to make the filter with human readable value?

Comment: What happens if you reproduce the same thing with a **Date** field?

Comment: The date filter is not working! When I apply it, the result still the same

Comment: I'd expect it needs a UNIX timestamp as input...

Comment: @leymannx, yes thank you! if I test with a value as **1538323253** the filter works well, but it's not what I need!

Comment: Then, please, completely rephrase your whole question.

Comment: Can you confirm whether `field_date` is a datetime or a timestamp, and if it is a datetime whether it is date+time or date-only?

Comment: @mpdonadio, filed_date is a timestamp

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I'd go around the problem, by adding a date field, either with JS or a template override kind of thing, and hide the timestamp visually. I'd then use JS to update the timestamp value based on the date field onChange/onBlur.

Comment: You need to create a custom exposed view filter to create our condition as you wish and use a field date in form exposed, here you can find a tutorial with a recipe to create your own exposed view filter : https://www.axelerant.com/resources/team-blog/creating-a-custom-exposed-view-filter-in-drupal-8-to-use-with-workflow-states

Comment: If you use date in format YYYY-MM-DD it should work, i just needed this for me.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue on D7. I [enabled the views query](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/109362/27710) and noticed that the values were being passed as human date to the query rather than timestamp.

So what I did was use [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/8.2.x) and converted them to timestamp.

Example code (D7 code)

```
function mymodule_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'list_employers') {
    foreach ($query->where[1]['conditions'] as $con_key => $con_val) {
      if ((strpos($con_val['field'], 'node.created = ') !== FALSE) &&
        empty($con_val['value'])) {
        $date = $con_val['field'];
        $date = str_replace('node.created = ', '', $date);
        $date = date('m/d/Y', $date);
        $start = strtotime($date . ' 12:00 AM'); // convert to timestamp
        $end = strtotime($date . ' 11:59 PM'); // convert to timestamp
        unset($query->where[1]['conditions'][$con_key]['value']); // remove default condition
        $query->where[1]['conditions'][$con_key]['field'] = 'node.created';
        $query->where[1]['conditions'][$con_key]['value'][0] = $start;
        $query->where[1]['conditions'][$con_key]['value'][1] = $end;
        $query->where[1]['conditions'][$con_key]['operator'] = 'BETWEEN';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before you have to enter a UNIX time into the text field.

If you want to use a date picker in the exposed filter in Drupal 8 have a look at this issue (currently there is a patch for that):

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2648950

[image: Drupal 8 Date picker]

Comment: About time, I was shaking my head when I had to come up with my solution.

Answer (score -3):

https://www.drupal.org/project/date_popup

This will add the native HTML 5 date popup widget to all date fields in views filters.

But this module won't work with timestamp fields.

Comment: OP doesn't use a date field. OP uses a timestamp field. Does Date Popup work with timestamp fields as well?

Comment: Oh! Yes, it won't work with timestamp fields. Updating my answer